# Using Excel VBA to change HTML attribute

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, queryselector

I am trying to change the HTML attribute within a class

```
<div class="treeNodeStyle" id="trMenu_14" nowrap="" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div class="treeNodeWrapperStyle" nowrap="">
        <a class="treeInlineStyle" onclick="FolderExpand('trMenu','14');return false;" href="">
            <img align="top" class="treeInlineStyle" src="/visimages/tree/plus.gif" border="0">
        </a>
        <div class="treeSelectorStyle" onclick="selectNode('trMenu','14',false)"
            ondblclick="dblselectNode('trMenu','14')">
            <img align="absmiddle" class="treeInlineStyleImg" src="/visimages/tree/folder.gif" border="0">
            <div title="Finance" class="treeNodeTextStyle" nowrap="true"> Finance</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class=”treeChildStyle” nowrap=”” style=”display: none;”> </div>
```

The last line of code is the one I need to change - from style=”display: **none**;” to style=”display: **block**;”

Here is the code I am attempting to use:

```
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("treeChildStyle").removeAttribute ("style")
IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("treeChildStyle").setAttribute "style", "display: block;"
```

Comment: mkay. so what's the question? does it work? does it blow up? does it summon Chtulu?

Comment: the `”` curly quotes are potentially a problem.

Comment: I am trying to change - style=”display: none;” to style=”display: block;”

Comment: Yes, I understand that. You still haven't told us what the problem was. Are you getting an error? What is the error? Is nothing happening at all? That's useful information too. Note the lack of a question mark in your question: we see what you're trying to do, but nothing about what the problem is. See [ask].

Comment: e.g. "I'm getting error 438 on this statement, why is that?", and then we could say "because getElement**s**ByClassName is giving you an *array of elements*, so you're missing an indexer/subscript e.g. `(0)` before the member call", ...without having to take a guess ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use querySelector to return single match then set the style attribute. Comment from @MathieuGuindon already points out error of attempting a method of a single node on a collection i.e. without an index.

```
ie.document.querySelector("#trMenu_14 .treeChildStyle").setAttribute "style", "display: block;"
```